# How to get column size smaller than col-xx-1

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my output : http://jsbin.com/zuxipa/1/

Basically,I want the 2nd div inside the row to be smaller(its currently at col-md-1).How can I do that?

Comment: Well, bootstrap is based on the grid system, so you'll probably have no specify a width, either px or %...

Comment: how will it affect the other grids and would the layout still be responsive?

Comment: i'd love to know how to do this as well. The below proposed answer does not really address the problem, as you'd have wasted space with that. If you want a single column that's 1/20 of the page, for instance, not 1/12, then are you just out of luck?

Comment: Just curious though, why do you need that? col-sm-1 is already very small to contain anything to be honest.

Comment: @LukeVo You might want a simple icon button to be in a single column, for example

Answer (score 21):

You can nest columns inside your `<div class="col-md-1"></div>` if you wrap them with a row

example:

```
<div class="col-md-1">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          2.1 col
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Comment: It seems unfair to downvote at this point, but this definitely doesn't answer the spirit of the question, even if it technically answers the title question...

Answer (score 14):

I'm not sure it was possible then, but it is now.

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-auto p-1"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
      <div class="col-8 p-1">You sent a message to Shanice</div>
      <div class="col">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Resend</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`col-auto`: Lets the column get as small as it can - it's just big enough for the content inside it. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#variable-width-content

`p-1`: Gives it almost the smallest possible padding. `p-0` was too small for what I needed. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/#notation

Answer (score 4):

I know it's late, but I was looking at ways to handle this and came across this question, so I thought I'd share my solution.

As far as I could find, there is no default way to handle this scenario in Bootstrap. What I did was removed the `.col-x` classes, but kept the `row` class. I then added a custom class to the sections and used percentage widths for the row I was dealing with. I ended up with the following:

```
<style>
    .section-1, .section-3 {
        width: 47%;
    }
    .section-2 {
        width: 6%;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="section-1">
            <!-- Content Here -->
        </div>
        <div class="section-2">
            <!-- Content Here -->
        </div>
        <div class="section-3">
            <!-- Content Here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that this in not responsive by default, but it would be easy to adjust the width percentages with media queries in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

hello i made this for you. put your class into your div it is now twice shorter than before

example: `col-custom-1 < col-xx-1`

```
.col-custom-1{
  flex: 0 0 4.16666%;
  max-width: 4.16666%;
}
.col-custom-2{
  flex: 0 0 8.3333%;
  max-width: 8.3333%;
}
.col-custom-3{
  flex: 0 0 12.5%;
  max-width: 12.5%;
}
.col-custom-4{
  flex: 0 0 16.6666%;
  max-width: 16.6666%;
}
.col-custom-5{
  flex: 0 0 20.83333%;
  max-width: 20.83333%;
}
.col-custom-6{
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
}
.col-custom-7{
  flex: 0 0 29.1666666667%;
  max-width: 29.1666666667%;
}
.col-custom-8{
  flex: 0 0 33.3333%;
  max-width: 33.3333%;
}
.col-custom-9{
  flex: 0 0 37.5%;
  max-width: 37.5%;
}
.col-custom-10{
  flex: 0 0 41.6666%;
  max-width: 41.6666%;
}
.col-custom-11{
  flex: 0 0 45.83333%;
  max-width: 45.83333%;
}
.col-custom-12{
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}
.col-custom-13{
  flex: 0 0 54.16666%;
  max-width: 54.16666%;
}
.col-custom-14{
  flex: 0 0 58.33333%;
  max-width: 58.33333%;
}
.col-custom-15{
  flex: 0 0 62.50000%;
  max-width: 62.50000%;
}
.col-custom-16{
  flex: 0 0 66.6666%;
  max-width: 66.6666%;
}
.col-custom-17{
  flex: 0 0 70.83333%;
  max-width: 70.83333%;
}
.col-custom-18{
  flex: 0 0 75.0000%;
  max-width: 75.0000%;
}
.col-custom-19{
  flex: 0 0 79.16666%;
  max-width: 79.16666%;
}
.col-custom-20{
  flex: 0 0 83.3333%;
  max-width: 83.3333%;
}
.col-custom-21{
  flex: 0 0 87.50000%;
  max-width: 87.50000%;
}
.col-custom-22{
  flex: 0 0 91.6666%;
  max-width: 91.6666%;
}
.col-custom-23{
  flex: 0 0 95.83333%;
  max-width: 95.83333%;
}
.col-custom-24{
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: oh i that time i did not realize this was 6,7 years ago bruh

Answer (score 1):

My situation was very same. But solve simple in bootstrap 5.2:

"col-auto"